# How do I create an in-app browser using PhoneGap and jQuery mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I am looking to mimic the behavior in the Twitter, Hootsuite, Facebook, etc. apps where external links in my app get opened in a browser window inside the app. I'm very new to PhoneGap, JQM and mobile development in general, so I think this is probably something simple that I'm not searching for in the right way.

I was thinking I should be using an iFrame, but it seems that iFrames and PhoneGap don't play nice?

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/51586852/iFrames%20and%20PhoneGap

Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT: Would like solution to be cross-platform compatible if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to take a look at the childbrowser plugin for phonegap.

iOS: https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/ChildBrowser

Android: https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowser

BB: https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/BlackBerry/ChildBrowser

WP: https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/WindowsPhone/ChildBrowser

It lets you display webpages inside your app. It is available for android, iOS, Blackberry and WindowsPhone.

Comment: It appears ChildBrowser is only an iPhone plugin, any ideas for xPlatform solutions? Editing original question to reflect xPlatform need.

Comment: Where did you get that the ChildBrowser is iOS only? It's available for Android, BB, and WindowsPhone too...

Comment: This project https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/ChildBrowser seems to be only iOS. This project https://github.com/alunny/ChildBrowser seems to be an attempt to make the plugin cross-platform compatible. Perhaps I am missing something?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the PhoneGap folk have added a child browsers, also known as [In App Browser](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser)